# Child Lock functionality

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is this possible to make an *Child Lock* app?

For example controlling the calls/texts/emails/photos/videos when child lock is on. Child can't do anything while child lock is on.

Any idea? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is purely on logic ... this is not an issue .... Wat u can do is add a password here and there ... Please think about it ...

Comment: U no need app for this

Comment: @amar why u troll ? :P

Comment: @Gill-TheIronMan Isn't this possible?

Comment: @Jeremy Is there any apple definition/documentation that providing this features aren't possible?

Answer (score 3):

In iOS, 3rd Party apps cannot control other apps. Dont think this is possible. You cannot control another app from your app unless the iPhone is jail broken. However you can get a list of processes in iOS as mentioned in this post. You can try to send SIGKILL to terminate them if you are not planning to release this app to appstore (Not recommended).

> But iOS 6 includes a new feature that lets parents lock the iPad to a
>   single app so kids cannot open other apps, post to Facebook or delete
>   apps from the iPad. The new iOS 6 software update includes Guided
>   Access mode, that locks the iPad to a single app, and allows blocking
>   certain areas of the screen or other features while the iPad is
>   locked. This may as well be called Kid Mode for the iPad.

Use Guided Access to:

- Temporarily restrict your iOS device to a particular app
- Disable areas of the screen that aren’t relevant to a task, or areas
  where an accidental gesture might cause a distraction
- Disable the hardware buttons

[image]

[[source]](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/10/01/how-to-lock-the-ipad-to-a-single-app-for-kid-mode/) and [[source]](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509)

Comment: Is there any apple definition/documentation that providing this features aren't possible?

Comment: i think there is. iOS provides a independent sandbox environment for each 3rd party apps. So from my app i cannot manipulate other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to say but this is ONLY possible within your app to what you want to lock or not. If you want that your app should Lock your default Phone calling system or texting service then it is not possible upto my knowledge as you want to do that from some app which is having its own Address Space i.e. sandBox. Means Every App is having its own Address Space which Other App Cannot Access it, as it will result in Crash.